# Installing Postgresql on Mac Lion

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

I was doing an exercise from the [ruby on rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#code%3apages_controller_spec_exercise) which involves installing postgresql. Following the instructions from a rails cast linked in the tutorial, I did

```
brew install postgresql
```

This errored. On searching online, found a thread on a [forum](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10157) which suggested doing

```
brew unlink ossp-uuid && brew link ossp_uuid
```

I don't know what this is achieving. The command failed (I think the first part succeeded). The error:

Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/ossp-uuid/1.6.2/share/man/man3/uuid.3
/usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable. You should change its permissions.

What is this about? Why do we need to create this symbolic link?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You likely need to use sudo before the command.

Alternatively, postgres can be installed from an installer from their site:  [Mac OS X installer](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/)

Comment: Did not try sudo. But used the installer instead. That worked. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't use `sudo` to `brew install` with [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation).

Answer (score 6):

You don't need sudo to work with brew [read here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation).

The main problem is your own permission on /usr/local folder to execute these actions.Try this (make sure that you login as administrator role):

`sudo chmod go+w /usr/local`

Then try again:

`brew unlink ossp-uuid && brew link ossp-uuid`

and:

`brew install postgresql`

Answer (score -2):

Postgresql is already installed on Lion.

Comment: This is true for OS X Lion Server, but not for Lion client.

Comment: Yea, but I wanted to install a newer version.